# Fluent NHibernte Alterations / Conventions

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, conventions

I like the pattern I saw in this blog post (http://marekblotny.blogspot.com/2009/04/conventions-after-rewrite.html), where the author is checking to see if a table name alteration has already been made before applying a convention.

```
public bool Accept(IClassMap target)
{
    //apply this convention if table wasn't specified with WithTable(..) method
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(target.TableName);
}
```

The convention interface I'm using for a string length is IProperty:

```
public class DefaultStringLengthConvention: IPropertyConvention
{
    public bool Accept(IProperty property) {
        //apply if the string length hasn't been already been specified
        return ??; <------ ??
    }

    public void Apply(IProperty property) {
        property.WithLengthOf(50);
    }
}
```

I don't see where IProperty exposes anything that tells me if the property has already been set. Is this possible?

TIA,
Berryl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify in code what Stuart and Jamie are saying, here's what works:

```
public class UserMap : IAutoMappingOverride<User>
{
    public void Override(AutoMap<User> mapping) {
        ...
        const int emailStringLength = 30;
        mapping.Map(x => x.Email)
            .WithLengthOf(emailStringLength)                        // actually set it
            .SetAttribute("length", emailStringLength.ToString());  // flag it is set
        ...

    }
}

public class DefaultStringLengthConvention: IPropertyConvention
{
    public bool Accept(IProperty property) {
        return true;
    }

    public void Apply(IProperty property) {
        // only for strings
        if (!property.PropertyType.Equals(typeof(string))) return;

        // only if not already set
        if (property.HasAttribute("length")) return;

        property.WithLengthOf(50);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`.WithLengthOf()` adds an "alteration" (`Action<XmlElement>`) to the list of alterations to apply when the XML mapping is generated. Unfortunately, that field is `private` and there is no property to access the alteration list, so I'm afraid there is (currently) no way to check if a property map has had `WithLengthOf` applied to it.

Comment: thought that might be the deal; I don't mind adding conventions for groups of string lengths but many cases are one-offs that are really driven by the class. So if an EmployeeNumber string length should be 6 chars it's either EmployeeNumberStringLengthConvention for the one field or an if statement in the DefaultStringLengthConvention.

Thx for the quick response.

Answer (score 1):

Until a better alternative comes along, you can use `HasAttribute("length")`.

Comment: That would be good enough, but it doesn't work. I haven't updated FNH in a few weeks - is that a recent update? Could the attribute be something other than "length"?

Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Berryl, HasAttribute should work if you use SetAttribute. As of revision 458, WithLengthOf stores the "length" attribute in a collection called columnProperties. SetAttribute stores in extendedProperties, which is also where HasAttribute looks. SetAttribute/HasAttribute have worked this way for as long as I can tell so it will probably work with whatever version you are using.